# Running powershell script From C# program behave different than when running directly

Tags: c#, powershell, iis

I have written a powershell script for creating website,

when i run script from powershell command prompt it runs perfect but when i run it through C# program sometime it wont work and some time it works.

and same for script for  creating apppoool. i have mention to create apppool for version 4.0 but through progam it create apppool of version 2.0

i have hosted my C# web application  in  IIS 7.5 ...i think this might be issue of IIS security

**Script:**

```
Import-Module WebAdministration -Force;

$siteName=$args[0];
$AppPoolName=$args[1];
$PortNumber=$args[2];
$PhysicalPath=$args[3];



New-Item IIS:\Sites\$siteName -physicalPath $PhysicalPath$siteName -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":"+$PortNumber+":"}
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$siteName -Name applicationPool -Value $AppPoolName
```

**C# code**

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();
            var runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force");
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            var appPoolName = new CommandParameter(null, command.SiteName);
            var siteName = new CommandParameter(null, command.SiteName);
            var scriptPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PowershellSscriptRootPath"];
            var websiteRootFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhysicalPathRoot"];
            var websitePath = websiteRootFolder + "\\" + command.SiteName + "\\";

            #region CreateWebsite

            string scriptPathForCreateWebsiteFromConfiguration = scriptPath + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CreateWebsiteScriptName"];
            var createWebsiteCommand = new Command(scriptPathForCreateWebsiteFromConfiguration);
            createWebsiteCommand.Parameters.Add(siteName);
            createWebsiteCommand.Parameters.Add(appPoolName);
            createWebsiteCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(null, "80"));
            createWebsiteCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(null, websiteRootFolder)); 
            pipeline.Commands.Add(createWebsiteCommand);

            #endregion
            pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide details of what exactly isn't working, for example, is there any error message that you could share here?

Comment: Check if runspace isn't PS2.0.

Comment: Maybe try it on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There is no any error but its not creating website .

but sometime it works!

strange :(

Comment: And who upvotes such questions??

Comment: @Vesper how to check runspace is PS2.0 or not

Comment: @Rajiv You might want to [check the pipeline for errors](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/b2bece71-72d7-4305-ad81-02139959e643/powershell-retrieving-pipeline-errors-in-c) before closing the runspace

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen
    var error = pipeline.Error.Read() as Collection<ErrorRecord>;

    error returns null

Answer (score 0):

If the port already in use which you want to bind to new site then it wont create new site